# Backup Hard drive with robocopy

Tags: backup, robocopy

I am trying to use robocopy to backup my entire hard drive to my external hard drive using the following code

```
ROBOCOPY C:\ "D:\HD Backup" /e /mir /tee /mt:4  /A-:SH /log:C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\backup_log_HD.txt
```

However it takes my 170GB from my hard drive and it was up to 400GB before I stopped it

Answer (score 1):

> ::
>      :: Remarks :
>      ::
>         Using /PURGE or /MIR on the root directory of the volume will
>         cause robocopy to apply the requested operation on files inside
>         the System Volume Information directory as well. If this is not
>         intended then the /XD switch may be used to instruct robocopy
>         to skip that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to add the `/XJ` flag to exclude junction points.

Answer (score 0):

add /ZB this will make uncopyable files "unlocked", you have to start Robocopy with admin privileges.

More information when it stopped and the error message would be helpful.